# How to transform a list to a 2D list like this [[1, 2, 3][4, 5, 6][7, 8, 9]]

Tags: python, list, matrix

i have a added data from a csv file into a list. But now is the list build like this:

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

How to transform a list in a 2D list like this:

[[1, 2, 3][4, 5, 6][7, 8, 9]]

```
lcsv=[]
newldata=[]

for column
    newldata.append(
    for row in lcsv:
        newldata.append(lcsv[1*row][0])
        newldata.append(lcsv[1*row][1])
        newldata.append(lcsv[1*row][2])
    )
```

what's wrong?

Comment: Very easily with `numpy`. As: `np.array(list_).reshape(3,3)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **list comprehension** combined with the **range** function:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
l = [l[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(l), 3)]
>>> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

The range function generates the numbers `[0, 6, 9, ..., len(l)]`, therefore the statement `l[i:i+3]` inside the list comprehension will put the sublists `l[0:3], l[3:6], and l[6:9]` into a new list.